# Why is Linux having more dependency issues than Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, dependencies

I have been using both Linux and Windows for the past eight years, and I feel that Linux has been having many more dependency issues than Windows while installing software. I like Linux more than Windows, but due to this problem I'm often forced to use Windows.

Comment: So, what is your problem exactly? Any examples?

Comment: I had problems many times. for example while installing eclipse for android,installing google chrome,virtual box etc. I just want to know why Linux is like that?

Comment: I still don't know "like what". Super User is a Q&A site and it works well for well-defined problems. I don't know how I could help you with your problem because I don't know what the problem is. We could probably help you with installing Eclipse for Android, Chrome or VirtualBox, but this question is just unclear to me.

Comment: If you install from your Linux distro repo using the distro's package install tool (e.g., yum, apt-get, etc.), the install tool will take care of all the dependencies for you.  If you install software from outside the repos, then you may have to install its dependencies.  These dependencies should be documented in the software install instructions or the install process will notify you of the missing dependencies.  You mention having trouble installing VirtualBox.  I installed from a repo and encountered no problems.  VirtualBox updates are also handled automatically by my package manager

Comment: @gronostaj How does x work / why does x word is a valid question. It shouldn't always be "Puter dead. How fix?".

Comment: What Linux problem "forced" you to use Windows?  I use Windows once a year because of TurboTax - but that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux relies on community led development to be up-to-date, while Windows relies on paid developers at Microsoft to push out patches and test, debug and fix proprietary code.

Take an audio driver, for example. Very few audio device manufacturers develop native drivers for Linux and in the few cases in which they do, they will only develop for one or two distributions. The nature of Linux being an open source operating systems means that the community around it can pickup that audio driver and port it to other distributions (this happens a lot of the time and is one of the main pluses Linux brings) but as a result, that audio driver port might rely and be dependent on other libraries, engines, versions of frameworks etc. Unlike commercial developers, open source ones do not have the luxury of testing and testing on common systems so as a result, dependencies are a major part of the environment.

[This video helps to explain the methods with which Linux is built and improved upon.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVpbFMhOAwE)

Comment: No problem - sorry it isn't more inclusive (it was meant to be) but I was in a rush!

Answer (score 3):

Linux and Windows often vary in the way they support dependencies.

Microsoft for example has been accused of being "Bloatware" because Microsoft packages just about everything as the core OS as an update.

This means more things work without any meddling by the end user or the business that sets up the Windows machine.

Linux varies distro by distro, and install package by package, but the Operating System often is designed to run leaner with only "essential" software and drivers. Drivers that are in one distro might not be in another, such as wireless NIC drivers or certain bits of software.

A good example of the differences of what comes with Linux would be to compare the install process of Ubuntu versus Arch.

Ubuntu more or less takes the Windows approach where everything the Ubuntu release thinks you might need is in the install disk, including Office applications. Whereas Arch "ships" with only the most fundamental of software and drivers, requiring the users to find, package and install their own software or drivers.